Error messages for static SVG files after next.js update to 14.2.12
We have a next.js app, that is using version 14.1.4. The app also uses some static SVG files and renders them using the next.js Image component. In the next.consig.js file we set dangerouslyAllowSVG: true.
When updated next.js to 14.2.12 we get error messages like this:
[ERR] Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot append headers after they are sent to the client 
[ERR]     at ServerResponse.appendHeader (node:_http_outgoing:715:11) 
[ERR]     at /app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:23801 
[ERR]     at _Headers.forEach (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:2510:22) 
[ERR]     at m (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:23783) 
[ERR]     at P (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:83072) 
[ERR]     at nq (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:69672) 
[ERR]     at n1 (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:81755) 
[ERR]     at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14) 
[ERR]     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:87775) 
[ERR]     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17) { 
[ERR]   code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT', 
[ERR]   digest: '592758662' 
[ERR] }

We could get rid of these errors by dropping the dangerouslyAllowSVG config setting and using the unoptimized prop on the Image component. But now, we get a different error, e.g.:
[ERR]  ⨯ The requested resource "/images/icons/power.svg" has type "image/svg+xml" but dangerouslyAllowSVG is disabled

How can I get rid of both errors, instead of replacing one with the other?
